# Typescript modify nested type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

i'm pretty new in typescript and can't figure out how i can modify deep nested interfaces.

I have interface ( which generated from graphql schema ) and i want to transform it to new model

it looks like so

```
interface SeatMap{
    // other fields
    segments: {
        // other fields
        rows: { // <-- i want to add one more field to row type
            // other fields
            seats: { // <-- i want to add few new fields to seat type
                isAvailable: boolean;
                isAisle: boolean;
                // etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Than, i'm create two new functions

addServiceFieldToSeats which receive SeatMap and return SeatMap with modified seat type

and addRowPartsToRows which receive SeatMap and return SeatMap with modified row type

then via compose function from redux to create new function `seatMapAdapter` but can't figure out how to solve typescript errors

[image]

i know that my function transform seatmap rows type to new type RowWithParts
but `addServiceFieldToSeats` receive old SeatMap type

How i can describe every SeatMap transformation?

Comment: Hello. Sorry I really don't understand your question. You have a generated interface,  but you want to modify it? Why don't you just open the file and edit the file?

Comment: Because this interface is auto generated from graphql schema and if i modify generated file, it returns to previous state after npm generate interfaces command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days of attempts, it looks like i find solution:

```
type NestedModelTransition<OriginalType, Compare, ReplaceWith> = {
    [Key in keyof OriginalType]: OriginalType[Key] extends Compare
        ? ReplaceWith
        : NestedModelTransition<OriginalType[Key], Compare, ReplaceWith>
};

type SeatMapWithSeatService = NestedModelTransition<SeatMap_SeatMap, SeatMap_SeatMap_segments_decks_rows_seats, Seat>;

type SeatMapWithRowWithParts = NestedModelTransition<
    SeatMapWithSeatService,
    SeatMap_SeatMap_segments_decks_rows,
    RowWithParts
>;
```

Comment: I think this is missing some parts to really flesh out what's happening.